# Why is startIndex not equal to endIndex shifted to startIndex position in String in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, indexing

Look at the program:

```
let s = "1"
print(s.startIndex)
print(s.index(before: s.endIndex))
print(s.index(before: s.endIndex) == s.startIndex)
```

It returns:

```
Index(_rawBits: 0)
Index(_rawBits: 256)
true
```

So, the same position in the string is represented with rawBits 0 and 256. Why?

Comment: Why are you looking at the `rawBits` at all?

Comment: maybe it's something with the print() command and not with the equality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raw bits of the index are an implementation detail. As you see in your example, the two values are equal (they return true for `==`).

As to the current implementation, bit 8 is set, which is not part of the position. [That's a cached value for the offset to the next grapheme cluster, which is 1 byte away.](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringIndex.swift#L25-L26) It's telling you that there's one byte to the next grapheme (which it didn't know until you calculated the endIndex).

Answer (score 3):

[Equality](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/671ae9494c3cc1daa99314c229fee149a938d093/stdlib/public/core/StringIndex.swift#L206) between two `String.Index`es is defined on the upper 50 bits of the `_rawBits`, aka [`orderingValue`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/671ae9494c3cc1daa99314c229fee149a938d093/stdlib/public/core/StringIndex.swift#L53), as follows:

> ```
> extension String.Index: Equatable {
>   @inlinable @inline(__always)
>   public static func == (lhs: String.Index, rhs: String.Index) -> Bool {
>     return lhs.orderingValue == rhs.orderingValue
>   }
> }
> ```

And since `0 &>> 14` and `256 &>> 14` both equal `0`, the positions are equal, and thus the indices are considered equal.

---

[`&>>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint64/2966034) is the infix operator to shift bits to the right, masking the shift amount to 64 bits.