# Inconsistent ranges of strings with greek letter

Tags: swift, string, range, nsstring

I'll show the code and the output, since it's easier to explain the issue.

Code and output in the commented lines:

```swift
let greekLetter = "β"

let string1 = greekLetter

/// string2 is the same as string1 but converted to NSString then back to String
let string2 = String(NSString(string: greekLetter))

print(string1.range(of: greekLetter)!)
/// prints: Index(_rawBits: 0)..<Index(_rawBits: 131072)

print(string2.range(of: greekLetter)!)
/// prints: Index(_rawBits: 0)..<Index(_rawBits: 65536)
```

The problem: A String that contains a greek letter returns a range that is different from the same String with the same greek letter that was converted to NSString and then back to String again.

Any ideas why?

Why this question is raised:
I'm doing some parsing and I need to find the range of specific string and then insert something else instead of it. Because of wrong ranges returned inserting strings in a wrong position due to wrong lower/upper bound location.

**UPDATE 2**:

Let's say I have a task: in a given string "β-1" change "1" to "2". And this string comes from the server.
Please look at this code sample:

```swift
let wordWithGreekLetter = "β-1"

var string1 = wordWithGreekLetter

let data = """
    { "name" : "\(wordWithGreekLetter)" }
""".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

struct User: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

let user = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data!)

/// string2 is the same as string1 but decoded from the data
var string2 = user.name

let rangeOfNumberOne1 = string1.range(of: "1")!
string1.removeSubrange(rangeOfNumberOne1)
string1.insert("2", at: rangeOfNumberOne1.lowerBound)
/// RESULT: string1 = "β-2"

let rangeOfNumberOne2 = string2.range(of: "1")!
string2.removeSubrange(rangeOfNumberOne2)
string2.insert("2", at: rangeOfNumberOne2.lowerBound)
/// RESULT: string2 = "β2-"
```

Comment: Why do you use `NSString` at all? Please add a concrete example what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/56066348/1187415: *“The raw bits of the index are an implementation detail.”* – Can you show a concrete example where something goes wrong?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use RegEx instead?

Comment: You will get the same result if you use `decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`  as `print(string1.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.range(of: greekLetter)!)`, `print(string2.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.range(of: greekLetter)!)`

Comment: [Swift strings and NSStrings](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E80-swift-string-vs-nsstring) have different concepts of what a character is; we can't convert a Range to an NSRange by simply counting indices, because they have a different index type. The female firefighter emoji with a skin tone modifier may look like a single character, but it isn't for an NSString.

Comment: @Kamran: That is correct, but does not apply here. `string1` and `string2` are both Swift strings  in example.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for your reply!please see an "update 1"

Comment: @vadian thanks! please see an "update 1"

Comment: @ToniNurmi I think I can use regex but since I already did it this parsing way I want to finish it this way. in case there is no other chances i'll try to do regex or something else. thanks!

Comment: @TungFam: I still don't see why this is a problem. As said in the referenced answer, the _rawBits are an implementation detail, and you should not care about that value.

Comment: And what is wrong in practice? Print both strings, they are the same. Compare both strings, they are the same. Count both strings, they are the same.

Comment: @MartinR please see update 2. Here I think it's more clear what is the issue.

Comment: @vadian please see update 2. Here I think it's more clear what is the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rob explained in [Why is startIndex not equal to endIndex shifted to startIndex position in String in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066091/why-is-startindex-not-equal-to-endindex-shifted-to-startindex-position-in-string/56066348#56066348), the raw bits of the index are an implementation detail, and you should not care about that value.

The actual problem is that (quote from [Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection)):

> Saved indices may become invalid as a result of mutating operations.

so that `rangeOfNumberOne1/2` may be no longer valid after you call `removeSubrange()` on the string.

In this particular case this *may* happen for `string2` (which is bridged from an `NSString`) because removing a character *may* reorganize the internal storage. But this is pure speculation: what matters only is that the current code exhibits undefined behavior.

If you replace

```
let rangeOfNumberOne1 = string1.range(of: "1")!
string1.removeSubrange(rangeOfNumberOne1)
string1.insert("2", at: rangeOfNumberOne1.lowerBound)
```

by

```
let rangeOfNumberOne1 = string1.range(of: "1")!
string1.replaceSubrange(rangeOfNumberOne1, with: "2")
```

(and similarly for `string2`) then you'll get  the same result "β-2" for both strings.

Comment: This is amazing. How couldn't I find this method... huh.. Thank you very much!