# Why end Index is not 2 when the collection length is 1?

Tags: swift, string, collections

can someone tell my why the end index is 524289?

```
let flag = ""
print(flag.startIndex)
print(flag.endIndex)
```

output:

```
Index(_rawBits: 1)
Index(_rawBits: 524289)
```

Comment: Swift strings are not indexed by integers, but `Index` objects, so looking at the raw numerical values of the `Index` objects won't make much sense either. You would need to know the [internal representation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/StringIndex.swift) of an `Index` to know _why_ it is 1 and 524289.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066091/1187415.

Answer (score 4):

Swift strings are not indexed by integers, but by `String.Index` objects, so looking at the raw numerical values of the Index objects won't make much sense either. You would need to look at the [internal representation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/StringIndex.swift#L16) of an Index to know *why* the start and end indices are 1 and 524289 respectively.

According to the comment in the code, the layout of the `rawBits` look like this:

```
 ┌──────────┬───────────────────╥────────────────┬──────────╥────────────────┐
 │ b63:b16  │      b15:b14      ║     b13:b8     │  b7:b1   ║       b0       │
 ├──────────┼───────────────────╫────────────────┼──────────╫────────────────┤
 │ position │ transcoded offset ║ grapheme cache │ reserved ║ scalar aligned │
 └──────────┴───────────────────╨────────────────┴──────────╨────────────────┘
```

Converting the end index 524289 to binary,

```
1000 00 000000 0000000 1
```

we can see that this index is scalar aligned, and has a position of 8. Everything else is 0. On the other hand, the start index 1 is only scalar aligned, and everything else is 0.

The position of 8 suggests that the internal representation of your string is in UTF-8 code units, as your string "" can be encoded in exactly 8 UTF-8 bytes:

```
0xf0 0x9f 0x87 0xb5 0xf0 0x9f 0x87 0xb7
```